# After taking the picture from CameraX, how can we preview our latest photo

Tags: android, kotlin

so I am making a different project, I'm making an app that has a normal camera using CameraX. My goal is when the photo is taken to go to a preview to see the latest photo directly before saving, examples such as "Messanger, Viber, Whatsapp and etc." does anyone has any idea how? Here is the code so far:

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Gradle implementation

```
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha21'
```

main_activity.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/previewView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/camera_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:backgroundTint="#B8AEAE"
        app:borderWidth="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.watermarkbitmap2

import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.*
import android.graphics.Color.BLACK
import android.graphics.Color.RED
import android.graphics.Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
import android.graphics.Paint.DITHER_FLAG
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.ColorInt
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    /**watermark private variables**/
    private var paint = Paint()
    private val config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    private val width = 15
    private val height = 15
    private var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config)

    /**Camera variables**/
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        /**Checking for all permissions to be granted through method,
         * if so it will start the camera, if not checks for a request with permissions and request code**/
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        // Making a variable, connecting to the button and setting up a listener to initiate taking a photo through a method
        val imageCaptureBtn = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.camera_button)
        imageCaptureBtn.setOnClickListener {
            takePhoto()
        }

        // Connecting the late init variable with a new method to get output directory
        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull().let {
            File(it, "BitmapWatermark").apply { mkdirs() } }
        return if (mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        val photoFile = File(outputDirectory, SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        imageCapture?.takePicture(
            outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object  : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val saveUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $saveUri"

                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Photo capture failed: ${exception.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    photoFile.delete()
                }

            }
        )

    private fun startCamera() {
        val viewFinder = findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.previewView)
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .build()

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun drawBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, left: Float, top: Float, paint: Paint?) {
        val paintText = Paint()

        paintText.textAlign
        paintText.textSize = 14F
        paintText.color = RED

        paintText.getTextPath(textText.toString(), 1, 10, 12f, 12f, path)
    }

    fun addWatermark(
        bitmap: Bitmap,
        watermarkText: String,
        options: WatermarkOptions = WatermarkOptions()
    ): Bitmap {
        val result = bitmap.copy(bitmap.config, true)
        val canvas = Canvas(result)
        val paint = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG or DITHER_FLAG)

        paint.textAlign = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> Paint.Align.LEFT
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
                Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> Paint.Align.RIGHT
        }

        val textSize = result.width * options.textSizeToWidthRatio
        paint.textSize = textSize
        paint.color = options.textColor

        if (options.shadowColor != null) {
            paint.setShadowLayer(textSize / 2, 0f, 0f, options.shadowColor)
        }

        if (options.typeface != null) {
            paint.typeface = options.typeface
        }

        val padding = result.width * options.paddingToWidthRation
        val coordinates = calculateCoordinates(watermarkText, paint, options, canvas.width, canvas.height, padding)
        canvas.drawText(watermarkText, coordinates.x, coordinates.y, paint)
        return result
    }

    private fun calculateCoordinates(
        watermarkText: String,
        paint: Paint,
        options: WatermarkOptions,
        width: Int,
        height: Int,
        padding: Float
    ): PointF {
        val x = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> {
                padding
            }
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> {
                width - padding
            }
        }

        val y = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT,
            Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> {
                height - padding
            }
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT -> {
                val bounds = Rect()
                paint.getTextBounds(watermarkText, 0, watermarkText.length, bounds)

                val textHeight = bounds.height()
                textHeight + padding

            }
        }
        return PointF(x, y)
    }

    enum class Corner {
        TOP_LEFT,
        TOP_RIGHT,
        BOTTOM_LEFT,
        BOTTOM_RIGHT,
    }

    data class WatermarkOptions(
        val corner: Corner = Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        val textSizeToWidthRatio: Float = 0.04f,
        val paddingToWidthRation: Float = 0.03f,
        @ColorInt val textColor: Int = Color.WHITE,
        @ColorInt val shadowColor: Int? = Color.BLACK,
        val typeface: Typeface? = null
    )

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "ExampleCameraPreview"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        private var path: Path = Path() // this gets us the new image
    }
}
```

Comment: To capture an image using `CameraX`, we will need a file to save that image. In your scenario, you can delete that photo at the preview screen in case the user discard it.

Comment: @HimanshuChoudhary The image file is saving in to the Internal Storage within the device(yes I am using a physical device for this matter). so it goes like this:
Internal storage/Android/media/com.example."ProjectName"/BitmapWatermark